# Creating two column article with only section title on one column

Tags: formatting

I am trying to create a class file of my own for a personally formatted CV. I would like to know how to create two column cv with one column containing only the section title while the others containing the contents. Also how can i create a box filled with color along the side of each line in the content side column.

Answer (score 6):

The [`multicol` package (link)](http://ctan.org/pkg/multicol) does exactly what you need, see the following example of its usage (you can replace `\lipsum` by any text material or whatever):

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{multicol}

\usepackage{lipsum} % for some dummy text

\begin{document}

\begin{multicols}{2}
  [\section{Section title that goes into both columns}]
\lipsum
\end{multicols}

\begin{multicols}{2}
  [\section{Section title that goes into both columns}]
\lipsum[11-20]
\end{multicols}

\end{document}
```

Edit: as egreg points out correctly, the section header should be put as an optional argument (as is now in the MWE), so that the first paragraph gets *correctly un-indented*.

Comment: Actually this is not what i wanted. I wanted to add margin note. I found the package marginnote and it helped me do the job.

Comment: @sgp That just shows how important is to **properly and state your question and even better to provide an image or what should be done, Minimal (non-)Working Example etc.**

Comment: sorry for the inconvenience. i am new to this forum and i am still learning. thanks for the advice.